# var vs int: var is undefined, int is OK

Tags: c#

Any idea why using `var velocity = ...` is giving me an undeclared error? When I used `int velocity = ...` it gives no errors.

```
// Error: Cannot use local variable 'velocity' before it is declared
var velocity = int.TryParse(txtVelocity.Text, out velocity) ? velocity : -1;

// Valid
int velocity = int.TryParse(txtVelocity.Text, out velocity) ? velocity : -1;
```

Comment: the problem is simply because you use velocity as out parameter, and in the ? syntax, that is where the compilation error is coming from.

Comment: Don't use the ternary operator this way.  Use an `if` statement.  This results in `velocity = velocity`, and the extra lines saved doesn't make up for the lack of logic.

Comment: I still don't get why people exagerate the use of var this way anyway. If you know the type, like is clearly the case here, use it. It documents intent.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: I was just curious why it worked this way, I am using the `int ` version.

Comment: @Jonesy: What logic is missing from this though? If the `TryParse` is successful, return the result. Otherwise `-1` is returned so I know if it failed or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the specs say so

You cannot use variables declared using `var` in initialization expression.

See: [Implicitly Typed Local Variables (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

> Variables declared by using var cannot be used in the initialization
>   expression. In other words, this expression is legal: 
>   `int i = (i = 20);` but this expression produces a compile-time error: 
>   `var i = (i = 20);`

Answer (score 5):

The fact is **var** keyword means **"I want a variable that I still don't know it's type, please Mr compiler find it's type for me"**.
And now you want to use that undetermined velocity var as an out parameter.
And that's impossible cause you are making a loop for compiler.